# Prove $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{x}{(\ln x)^3} = \infty$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{(\ln x)^3} = \infty$$

One way to think of this problem is in terms of the relative growth rates between the numerator and denominator. I know that $x$ grows asymptotically faster than $(\ln x)^3$ according to WolframAlpha. How can I prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{(\ln x)^3}=\quad\quad  (\frac{\infty}{\infty}\textrm {form, using L'Hospital  rule})\\ =\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{3(\ln x)^2}\quad\quad  (\frac{\infty}{\infty}\textrm {form, using L'Hospital  rule})\\=\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{6(\ln x)}\quad\quad  (\frac{\infty}{\infty}\textrm {form, using L'Hospital  rule})\\ =\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{x}{6}=\infty$

Answer (score 2):

Put $y = \ln x \implies x = e^y\implies L = \displaystyle \lim_{y \to \infty} \dfrac{e^y}{y^3}$. Can you do Lhospitale three times? or you can use Lhospitale rule directly from the original form above.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may observe that, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
x=e^{\ln x}>1+\ln x+\frac1{2!}(\ln x)^2+\frac1{3!}(\ln x)^3+\frac1{4!}(\ln x)^4
$$giving, as $x \to \infty$,$$
\frac{x}{(\ln x)^3}>\frac{1}{(\ln x)^3}+\frac{1}{(\ln x)^2}+\frac{1}{2\cdot(\ln x)}+\frac{1}{3!}+\frac{1}{4!}\cdot\ln x
$$ and the latter tends to $\infty$.